# Error when trying to install OpenShift 4 on Libvirt: qemu-kvm: -fw_cfg: invalid option

Tags: openshift, qemu, kvm, libvirt, openshift-enterprise

I'm trying to install OpenShift 4.2.8 on libvirt and I'm stuck with the following error when running `./bin/openshift-install create cluster --log-level=debug --dir=initial`

```
 internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu-kvm: -fw_cfg: invalid option
```

here's more about the issue:

```
<pre><font color="#D3D7CF">DEBUG</font> module.bootstrap.libvirt_volume.bootstrap: Creating... 
<font color="#D3D7CF">DEBUG</font> libvirt_volume.master[0]: Creating...        
<font color="#D3D7CF">DEBUG</font> module.bootstrap.libvirt_ignition.bootstrap: Creation complete after 40s [id=/var/lib/libvirt/openshift-images/mycluster-dq8fj/mycluster-dq8fj-bootstrap.ign;5df28fa3-7654-1f49-8711-00d834f9b123] 
<font color="#D3D7CF">DEBUG</font> module.bootstrap.libvirt_volume.bootstrap: Creation complete after 5s [id=/var/lib/libvirt/openshift-images/mycluster-dq8fj/mycluster-dq8fj-bootstrap] 
<font color="#D3D7CF">DEBUG</font> module.bootstrap.libvirt_domain.bootstrap: Creating... 
<font color="#D3D7CF">DEBUG</font> libvirt_volume.master[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed] 
<font color="#D3D7CF">DEBUG</font> libvirt_volume.master[0]: Creation complete after 10s [id=/var/lib/libvirt/openshift-images/mycluster-dq8fj/mycluster-dq8fj-master-0] 
<font color="#D3D7CF">DEBUG</font> libvirt_domain.master[0]: Creating...        
<font color="#CC0000">ERROR</font>                                              
<font color="#CC0000">ERROR</font> Error: Error creating libvirt domain: virError(Code=1, Domain=10, Message=&apos;internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu-kvm: -fw_cfg: invalid option&apos;) 
<font color="#CC0000">ERROR</font>                                              
<font color="#CC0000">ERROR</font>   on ../../../../../openshift-install-216670211/main.tf line 87, in resource &quot;libvirt_domain&quot; &quot;master&quot;: 
<font color="#CC0000">ERROR</font>   87: resource &quot;libvirt_domain&quot; &quot;master&quot; {   
<font color="#CC0000">ERROR</font>                                              
<font color="#CC0000">ERROR</font>                                              
<font color="#CC0000">ERROR</font>                                              
<font color="#CC0000">ERROR</font> Error: Error creating libvirt domain: virError(Code=1, Domain=10, Message=&apos;internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu-kvm: -fw_cfg: invalid option&apos;) 
<font color="#CC0000">ERROR</font>                                              
<font color="#CC0000">ERROR</font>   on ../../../../../openshift-install-216670211/bootstrap/main.tf line 13, in resource &quot;libvirt_domain&quot; &quot;bootstrap&quot;: 
<font color="#CC0000">ERROR</font>   13: resource &quot;libvirt_domain&quot; &quot;bootstrap&quot; { 
<font color="#CC0000">ERROR</font>                                              
<font color="#CC0000">ERROR</font>                                              
<font color="#CC0000">FATAL</font> failed to fetch Cluster: failed to generate asset &quot;Cluster&quot;: failed to create cluster: failed to apply using Terraform</pre>
```

can someone help me fix this problem? 
Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an outdated version of qemu-kvm that does not understand this parameter.

You can use the Virtualization SIG version of qemu-kvm using these 2 commands:
yum install centos-release-qemu-ev
yum update qemu-kvm-ev

This can be done on an existing installation of qemu-kvm
 (as I did, using CentOS 7.7).

Hope this helps someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

fix is here for anyone facing the same problem: https://github.com/openshift/installer/issues/1183